# "I Like It" button on Sharepont 2010

Tags: social

I'm very new at this field, so my question might be so simple and "stupid".

I was following instructions on the book "Sharepoint 2010 for dummies", and it says that I can share documents by clicking "I like it" button. the problem that I can't find that button anywhere. Should I change some permissions? or is there something to install first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the [socialribboncontrol](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721062.aspx) feature is activated.

It should already be.

User profiles and my sites have to be setup too.

When you click I Like It, the item (list, page etc) is added to your profile page in mysites for others to see.

Here is how to setup the [user profile service](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-the-user-profile-service-in-sharepoint-2010/).

Here is how to setup [My Sites](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362.aspx).

Comment: wow, you mentioned a lot of stuff I've never heard before lol. I think I need a dummy"ER" book. can you recommend me any book for absolute beginner? oh and thanks for your answer

Comment: Glad to help! In my experience download a sample SharePOint VM with everything setup, then have a play and see how it all connects together.  There is a lot of stuff in SharePoint, dont attempt to learn it all at once.  Hands on practice with SharePoint will help explain a lot that books can't.  There is so much on the web, google is your friend for SharePoint. :) Also StackOverflow can help. :)