# Like It Button on Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, like

I want to make a button Like it in Sharepoint 2010 to visible for everybody on the Intranet Site could see, and everybody could push this button and see how many person like it. How I Could do it on the List and Count a element that user liked?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I add a Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a "Like" button, have a look at this question 
["I Like It" button on Sharepont 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25424/i-like-it-button-on-sharepont-2010)

So you already have that functionality, you can programmatically access these RATINGS as well..

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://servername.com/finance/Finance/");

using (SPSite site = new SPSite("https://servername.com/finance/Finance/"))
{
   // Get the context of the service application
   SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);

   // SocialTagManager - Contains methods and properties used to manipulate social tag data
   SocialTagManager socialTagManager = new SocialTagManager(context);

   // GetTags(Uri) method is used to retrieve an array of SocialTag objects that are owned by the current user and that contain the specified URL.
   SocialTag[] tags = socialTagManager.GetTags(uri);  
}
```

Add reference to "Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll", and `using Microsoft.Office.Server.SocialData;` to be able to use SocialTagManager class

You can create a custom control which shows a count of Likes at the top of each page (maybe include this control in custom MasterPage)

**Sources**

[Programmatically get all the Social Tags for the specified URL in SharePoint 2010](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/programmatically-get-all-the-social-tags-for-the-specified-url-in-sharepoint-2010/)